# Grey ribbon on Account form in IE "SCRIPT5: Access is denied." in PageLoader.js

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, dynamics-crm-2011, access-denied

MS CRM 2011 on premise.

No problems if accessed via internal address: crm:5555

Go to crm.ourcompany.co.uk:5555 in IE and load account page and the ribbon is totally grey. (Not disabled - every pixel is the colour grey.)
[image]

In Chrome and Firefox the ribbon is loaded fine.

Browser console in IE, Chrome and FF all say access errors.

I can see they are trying to access crm:5555.

IE says:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

PageLoader.js, line 1 character 1226
```

The second line above is presented as a link. Clicking it shows me this: http://pastebin.com/bBadk9HS

The full path is http://crm.ourcompany.co.uk:5555/_static/_common/scripts/PageLoader.js?ver=-1056260279

P.S. IE is "Browser Mode: IE10   Document Mode: IE9 standards".

Comment: did you try to add the site to the compatibility view settings?

Comment: Do you have custom javascript that is running to enable / show buttons on the ribbon?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Just done so but no difference

Comment: I have same issue but do have any luck

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462988/crm-2011-ribbon-bar-missing-after-applying-update-rollup-14-in-ie-not-the-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is an address lookup plugin on the Account form.

This is trying to access `http://crm:1999`, which is a 404, and `http://crm:5555`, which isn't allowed.

Solutions are to fix the server on `http://crm:1999` and set up proper managed internal and external URLs so it'll know whether `http://crm:5555` or `http://crm.ourcompany.co.uk:5555` or remove the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

After Long investigation I have found out the reason for same issue like this. 
We had previous rollup activity feed solution.
After importing the new version of Activity feeds this hectic issue was sorted out.

Activity feed new solution is available with rollup up package.it can be found by exacting the rollup package. Previously this was available in Microsoft Dynamic market place.