# CRM 2011 Ribbon bar Missing after applying update Rollup 14 in IE not the chrome or Firefox?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

When reviewing issue further, I have found out  below solution:
Log in to CRM as an administrator.

1. Go to Settings > Administration.
2. Click System Settings.
3. On the “Customizations” tab, uncheck Load pages in the most recent version of Internet Explorer.

Even this one is not working for me.
I am getting below error in page load event in IE not the chrome or Firefox

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

PageLoader.js, line 1 character 1226

I am stuck with as my production release on Monday. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: CRM Error is <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Access is denied.
</Message>
   <Line>1</Line>
   <URL>/_static/_common/scripts/PageLoader.js?ver=-1719327021</URL>
   <PageURL>/main.aspx?etc=10159&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d10159%26etc%3d10159%26id%3d%257b81C56D27-3CAA-E211-88A2-00155D007B0C%257d%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1382241889847%26rskey%3d406063542&pagetype=entityrecord</PageURL>
   <Function>executeAction(action)</Function>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Long two days investigation I have found out the reason for the issue. We had previous rollup activity feed solution. After importing the new version of Activity feeds this hectic issue was sorted out.

Activity feed new solution is available with rollup up package.it can be found by exacting the rollup package. Previously this was available in Microsoft Dynamic market place.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any script that have fixed url?
Seems similar issue with:
[Grey ribbon on Account form in IE "SCRIPT5: Access is denied." in PageLoader.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545918/grey-ribbon-on-account-form-in-ie-script5-access-is-denied-in-pageloader-js)

And try IIS Reset might help clearing cached content.

Comment:  If any issue comes out first thing we do is IIS Reset and CRM async service restart. We did everything but no luck so far.
We went through the link you have provided and it is not the reason.
Surprisingly when we restore the back of the database in other rollup 14 environment it still give the error and not for the other organization.

Comment: Try to start debugger on IE, usually it gives some exception that more clear.

Comment: it gives the below error SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

PageLoader.js, line 1 character 1226

Comment: Is there any part of javascript code that trying to access external domain (cross domain ajax call)?

Comment: There are script in other pages.But in this error give in all the form in organization.Also this is happening when opening record.When creating new record this not an issue but after saving record cannot load.

Comment: <CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Access is denied.
</Message>
   <Line>1</Line>
   <URL>/_static/_common/scripts/PageLoader.js?ver=-1719327021</URL>
   <PageURL>/main.aspx?etc=10159&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d10159%26etc%3d10159%26id%3d%257b81C56D27-3CAA-E211-88A2-00155D007B0C%257d%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1382241889847%26rskey%3d406063542&pagetype=entityrecord</PageURL>
   <Function>executeAction(action)</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>executeAction(action)</Function>

Comment: 1 more question, is this happening on opening all kind of record? try to open any record that does not have any form scripting, specifically onload. It could be the issue from the javascript being loaded asynchrounously. Are you upgrading from prior UR 12? There is a discussion regarding the asynchronous javascript loading:
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdca4779-e866-4e51-bab9-97a159f9cd37/rollup-12-problem-with-web-resources-and-jquery?forum=crmdevelopment. Otherwise, installing UR 15 will fix the asynchronous issue.